Spark dataframe not inferring the column data type properly
I am loading the multiple parquet under a directory but the data type for one of the column is not inferring properly the column has the value like this "2023-03-02 00:00:00". I tried a couple of setting below-mentioned on the internet and stackoverflow
Reading the parquet file with inferSchema and timestampformat
 val Input_Df = spark.read.option("inferSchema",true).option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS").parquet(Input_Path)

Adding the below setting to the spark configuration
val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
    conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "LEGACY")
    conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "LEGACY")
    conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "LEGACY")
    conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "LEGACY")
    conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference","TRUE")
    conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead","LEGACY")
    conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.int96AsTimestamp","TRUE")
    conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled","TRUE")
        
        val spark: sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName(s"Load_Oracle_Date").config(conf).getOrCreate()

But when I try to printSchema of the dataframe it still shows the column type is string. I want to dynamically update the column type, so that's why I am not using the structType to define the schema or spark sql to convert the dataframe and apply casting on the columns. I am using sparkVersion 3.2.1

Parquet files hold the schema within itself, there is no schema inference when reading parquet.

yes i agree i didn't face this issue before it was properly inferring the schema but this column is very interesting

thats because this column was saved as string by the writer

I would say check out the parquet files that have a different schema and adapt them first. If this is not working I would go for a try except mechanism. First try the normal reading and casting and then the second case.
